# Do you split your data into 2 subsets (train, hold-out/test) when using cross validation or not?

Tags: data-science, cross-validation, resampling

I know there are several resampling methods to avoid overfitting. In many tutorials and books (i.e. introduction to statistical learning Ch. 5 Resampling methods) I see, train and validation splits **or** k-folds cross validation being used. However, there are also many tutorials that combine **both** methods.(i.e. split the data into 3 parts: training, validation, test or use cross validation on train only on the train subsets, but still split in train and test)

This confuses me quite a bit. As I understood it, cross validation is a repeated train validation split. This way you will avoid evaluating the performance of your model(s) on only one split, which by chance might be easy (or super hard) to predict and therefore not providing you with an accurate estimate of the actual performance of your model(s). By repeating the process of splitting the data in train and validation several times and averaging the performance metrics over all these splits, you get a better view of the real performance of the model.

So why do some split in train and test subsets and then use cross validation only train and leave the test data totally hidden from the model? To me this seems "wrong". Because as I understand it now, it looks like you are *reintroducing* the problem cross validation is trying to solve in the first place. Or am I missing something?

Would it not be better to only use **k-folds cross validation** (which is basically a repeated split in train and test subsets and) on **all** the data and **not splitting in train and test**? Instead of splitting in train and test subsets and only cross validating on the train?

Thanks

Comment: The point of not using the test data is to test the model on unseen data (unseen by your model). If you also use the test data to train the model, then test data has some influence in predictions. That 's why we use training data to train our model, cross validation data to validate our model is working as it is trained and finally we use test data to make sure we have trained our model that can generalize (have learned the patterns not the data).